# Reacting to changes in derived state with redux

Tags: redux, architecture

I'm using redux at a pretty complicated project. It has a lot of complicated action creators, reducers and selectors. I need to trigger a certain action if some derived state, which is computed via selectors, changes.

The naive way of implementing it would be to go through all the action creators that could change it and insert triggers there. However, it's bad because it's a lot of repetitive code and it doesn't safeguard from adding some action in the future that can change that derived state without this trigger.

Previously, this was achieved via React `useEffect` which had all derived state as dependencies. It was a very clean and effective way of reacting to changes in state. However, now I need to move this logic to be redux-only.

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like an excellent use case for the Redux Toolkit "listener" middleware, which specifically has the ability to run reactive logic in response to both specific action types, and state-based conditions. A basic example

```
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  predicate: (action, currentState, previousState) => {
    // Trigger logic whenever this field changes
    return currentState.counter.value !== previousState.counter.value
  },
  effect: (action, listenerApi) => {
    // run arbitrary sync or async logic here, 
    // including dispatching actions, reading state, and much more
  }
})
```

See the Redux docs and these articles for more details:

- [Redux docs: Using Redux > Side Effects Approaches](https://redux.js.org/usage/side-effects-approaches)
- [RTK docs: `createListenerMiddleware` API reference](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware)
- [Idiomatic Redux: Designing the RTK Listener Middleware](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2022/03/designing-rtk-listener-middleware/)
- [Reactathon 2022: The Evolution of Redux Async Logic](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2022/05/presentations-evolution-redux-async-logic/)

Comment: It does! Thank you, I was under a mistaken impression that middlewares work _before_ the state has been updated, not _after_.

Comment: They do _both_! Middleware wrap around `dispatch` and form a pipeline. Normally a middleware calls `next(action)`. Any code _before_ that line runs _before_ the reducer updates the state. Any code _after_ that line runs _after_ the state is updated. So, a middleware can intentionally do work both before and after the state update. It's just a question of when you call `next(action)`. For example, the listener middleware _only_ checks to see what listeners need to run _after_ the state has been updated.